# Row wise outlier/anomaly detection based on the values given in one column (in array format)

Tags: python, r, csv, machine-learning

I have been trying to find a way through Python or R where in the csv file that I have, the script should go through each row and try to detect outliers or anomalies based on the array values in one of the columns.

The issue is quite complex according to me and I have exhausted myself trying to go through methods which detect anomalies or outliers.

Should I look into Machine Learning for such an issue?

There is [already a question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938398/row-wise-outlier-detection-in-python) for similar kind of thing but it has not been answered correctly (I feel), the image of the data given there can be used to describe any plausible answer.

Thanks

[I would like to find the outliers in the Values column, for example, in the first row 142 would be an outlier when compared to other values in the cell, i want something which would go ID wise (row by row) and write the outliers to a new file with all these columns in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrTS8.png)

Comment: errrmmm how would you define outlier? It's one variable show you don't need machine learning. Can you provide an example of one csv file? And whats the end point after removing outliers?

Comment: I would define an outlier based on the other values which are present in the same cell, in a range of 170-180, if there is a value of 142, it would be an outlier for me. So far I just want to identify the outliers and write them to a new file and not remove them.

Comment: can you provide an example of your csv file? Otherwise how can anyone know what format your csv file looks like, or what columns are there?

Comment: I have added the image above, in the edited part, if you would click on "I would like to..." you'll find the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is something to get you starting. So let's say we define outliers to be something that is more than 2 standard deviations from the mean, we can do the below. Before you read on, bear in mind doing something like this on limited data points is risky, because you have not observed enough of the data to know it is an outlier!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(1,6),
                   'lat':np.array([43,44,45,47,48]),
                   'lon':np.array([16,5,12,13,17]),
                   'values':[[171,172,142,169,178,180],[27,150,151,162,159,165],
                             [151,153,152,37],[171.222,127,180,172.56],[np.nan]]
                  })
```

We can look at df:

```
    id  lat     lon     values
0   1   43  16  [171, 172, 142, 169, 178, 180]
1   2   44  5   [27, 150, 151, 162, 159, 165]
2   3   45  12  [151, 153, 152, 37]
3   4   47  13  [171.222, 127, 180, 172.56]
4   5   48  17  [nan]
```

We define a function that returns data points to those outside 2 sd of the mean:

```
def func(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    x_mean = np.mean(x)
    x_sd = np.std(x)
    return(x[abs(x - x_mean)>2*x_sd])
```

Now we make a new data frame:

```
newdf =df.copy()
newdf['outlier_values'] = newdf['values'].apply(func)
newdf
```

Results look like:

```
id  lat     lon     values  outlier_values
0   1   43  16  [171, 172, 142, 169, 178, 180]  [142]
1   2   44  5   [27, 150, 151, 162, 159, 165]   [27]
2   3   45  12  [151, 153, 152, 37]     []
3   4   47  13  [171.222, 127, 180, 172.56]     []
4   5   48  17  [nan]   []
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this will definitely help me a lot and is sure to get me started !

Comment: Cool. Really glad it got you started :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an entropy based approach would  work here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.380.4114&rep=rep1&type=pdf

In short, entropy is the measure of disorder. So you can "measure" the disorder of your rows by calculating the row entropy. It is a relative measure so you will have to try and determine what is precise for your case (this is not an exact science).

Here is an example:

```
from scipy.stats import entropy


def my_entropy(labels, base = None):
    value,counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
    return entropy(counts, base=base)  

ls = [ [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1], [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,9,1] , [1,0,1,'A',1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1], [1,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,7,1,0,1] ]

res = []
for labels in ls:
    res.append(my_entropy(labels))

print(res)
#[0.6365141682948128, 0.887694275799104, 0.8239592165010823, 1.14370838942625]
```

res here ranks the list based on the disorder. In the first case we only have zeros and ones so the entropy is the lowest. Different outliers introduced in other 3 lists noticeably increase the entropy. So one can use entropy here as a quality measure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Can you please add more details from your link in your answer? Imagine that the link might go dead in a few years, your answer would need to stand on its own.

Comment: Hi, I am like really really new to python,r and machine learning. If you could please elaborate then it would be the best, thank you!